# Como comparar duas colunas DateTime Oracle

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, select, comparação

Eu tenho uma coluna onde eu insiro uma data quando o evento acontece (armazenamento local), ea data em que o evento é enviado para o meu sistema.

A diferença entre a data do evento e a data de envio não pode ser superior a 168 horas (7 dias).

Eu gostaria de selecionar todos os dados que os dados do evento + 168h é menor do que os dados de envio.

```
SELECT * FROM VENDA
WHERE (DATA_VENDA+ 168HOURAS) < DATA_ENVIO_VENDA;
```

Estou usando banco de dados Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode adicionar 7 dias que é o equivalente a 168h:

[SQLFiddle - Exemplo Online:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/969bb/2)

```
SELECT * FROM VENDA WHERE (DATA_VENDA + 7) < DATA_ENVIO_VENDA
```

Comment: Isso vai levar em consideração a hora também ou apenas a data?
exemplo: venda dia 01/xx/xxxx as 12:00:00 e o envio dia 08/xx/xxxx as 11:59:00, isso me dará um falso positivo? De toda forma vou testar.

Comment: Levará em consideração a hora sim, no exemplo que você deu a condição do `where` não será satisfeita e portanto não retornará essa linha. Atualizei o exemplo que está no link da resposta para simular sua dúvida.